# if statement use in protractor searching for element present on screen

Tags: protractor

I am using following code to verify if the linkText is present then do something else do something else but every time it gives me error LinkText not present
following is the code

```
if(expect(element(By.linkText('ramit')).isDisplayed()))
{
    b();
}
else
{
    a();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do it that way, `expect` is for test assertions.  You need to resolve the promise and perform your conditional statement on the returned value.  For example:

```
element(By.linkText('ramit')).isDisplayed().then(function(val) {
    if(val === true) {
      //code
    }
    else {
      //code
    }
});
```

And you mentioned the error is LinkText not present, if your site is Angular it should synchronize appropriately and wait for any requests to complete before executing tests.  If not, I'd advise you to look at [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)

Answer (score 0):

We can check whether element or link or text is present on UI or Not using **protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf()** method. Code snippet for checking element visibility is as follows:

```
 var EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;
 var linkText=element(By.linkText('ramit'));
 EC.visibilityOf(linkText).call().then(function(isLinkTextPresent){
            if(isLinkTextPresent){
                     //do the logic if link text is present
            }else{
                  //do the logic if link text is not present
            }
    });
```